# Joining onto itself in BigQuery

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I have this code that works in MySQL but haven't managed to get it run in BigQuery.

```
select *
from table1 
left join table1 as table2
on table1.user_id = table2.user_id
and table1.date = table2.date - interval '1 day'
```

I'm probably missing something fundamental here but can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you get an error message? and why is 1 day quoted?

Comment: yep, I'm getting an error message in BigQuery. Syntax error: Unexpected keyword INTERVAL at [10:58]

Comment: Ok Please publish it

Comment: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword INTERVAL at [10:58]

Comment: it seems that BigQuery does not support INTERVAL. Try to replace with DATEADD().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DATE_SUB() function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_sub)

```
select *
from table1 
left join table1 as table2
on table1.user_id = table2.user_id
and table1.date = DATE_SUB(table2.date, interval 1 day);
```

PS. `INTERVAL` datatype/specificator not found in User Manual. [BigQuery - DATATYPES](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types).

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery Standard SQL now supports [DATE arithmetic operators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#date_arithmetics_operators).

So (assuming `table1.date` and `table2.date` are of date type) you can do just as simple as

```
select *
from table1 
left join table1 as table2
on table1.user_id = table2.user_id
and table1.date = table2.date - 1
```